# react-three-fiber rotate around a certain axis

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am using react-three-fiber and I want to rotate my mesh at a certain axis and angle. Where do I add something like "setRotationfromAxisAngle" in react-three-fiber

```
<mesh>
  <geometry/>
  <material/>
</mesh>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Rafter axis={new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0)} angle={Math.PI/2} />

...

const Rafter = (props) => {

  const ref = useUpdate(group => {
    group.rotateOnAxis(props.axis,props.angle)
  }, [])

  return (
    <group ref={ref}>
      <mesh>
        <geometry/>
        <material/>
      </mesh>
    </group>
  )

}
```

You can also use the `rotateX, rotateY, and rotateZ` methods.

```
  const ref = useUpdate(group => {
    group.rotateX(props.angle)
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set it with a prop

```
<mesh rotation-y={radians}>
  <geometry/>
  <material/>
</mesh>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use groups as pivot points. each object has a rotation prop that you can set.